# Can this query be rewritten without UNION, and is it scaleable?

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, join

I have a few tables:

- In the `product`-table, I have a list of products.
- In the `user`-table, I have a list of users.
- In the `group`-table, I have groups of users.
- IN the `group_member`-table, I have linked `group` and `member` (many-to-many)
- In the `user_product`-table, I have linked `user` and `product` (many-to-many)
- In the `group_product`-table, I have linked `group` and `product` (many-to-many)

So a user could have many products, a product could have many users. A user can be member of many groups, a group could have many members. A group could have many products, a product could have many groups. In other words, a product can have both groups and users.

What I want to ask the database is: "List all the products that a given `user` has access to, either through a direct relation in the `user_product`-table, or through the groups that the user is member of. I want the name of the product and the name of the user."

This is the query that I have come up with:

```
# First get all the products the user has access to via a group.
SELECT product.name,
       user.first_name
FROM product
       INNER JOIN group_product
               ON group_product.product_id = product.product_id
       INNER JOIN group
               ON group.group_id = group_product.group_id
       INNER JOIN group_member
               ON group_member.group_id = group.group_id
       INNER JOIN user
               ON user.user_id = group_member.user_id
WHERE user.user_id = 1

UNION 

# Now get all the products via direct access from user_product.
SELECT product.name,
       user.first_name
FROM product
       INNER JOIN user_product
               ON user_product.product_id = product.product_id
       INNER JOIN user
               ON user.user_id = user_product.user_id
WHERE user.user_id = 1
```

Is this a good query, or is it better/possible to rewrite this into a JOIN only query? Would this be a fast query if there were 100 000 users, 10 000 groups and 100 products?
Is this a good database design, or is it better to store this logic in another manner?

(This is my first more complex query.)

Comment: Yes: you could put the {{group_product*group*group_member} + {user_product}} into a smaller union in the middle, or avoid the union and use two left joins + coalesce, (or a carthesian product * EXISTS {3-table join} OR EXISTS {user_product}). It's not hard, its just work. CTEs might help, too, but mysql doesn't have CTEs

Comment: What does `EXPLAIN` tell you about this query?

Comment: @wildplasser Woah, will this be more scaleable? If so, please add a more detailed answer! :D I mean, if this isn't just something that is possible. I'm not after eliminating the UNION, I'm after performance.

Comment: @JanDvorak I'm really a bit new to larger-scale databases, and I haven't used EXPLAIN, though I will try it and report back.

Comment: @JanDvorak The EXPLAIN gives me 6 rows of information. I suppose you were interested in the `rows` and where it uses an index. I have optimized the indexes. But, the `rows` is always 1 for some reason. I haven't used `EXPLAIN` before, so I'm not experienced with it. As of right now, there are two users, two groups, six products. So runs in 1.2ms right now...

Comment: I think `rows` is how many rows it expects to match the index. `Rows = 1` might mean "this looks like a unique index. I'll use it". In that case, `1` is the optimal value (unless it's wrong)(`0` means "no idea")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query has the correct approach for your data model. The "correctness" of your data model really depends on volumes and frequency of change- you could opt to always store the explicit user-product relationship whenever a user is added to or removed from a group. This is a denormalizing tactic and moves the overhead from querying to updating - usually best not to consider these moves unless performance is tested and deficient.

A very tiny optimisation may be to avoid the join to user and product until after the union. At present you are only selecting the product name and user first_name, but if you were selecting many columns the sort/distinct would involve more work than strictly necessary, so something like:-

```
select product.name, user.first_name
from
(
select 
group_product.product_id
from  
group_product
inner join group on group.group_id = group_product.group_id
inner join group_member on group_member.group_id = group.group_id
where group_member.user_id = 1
union
select product_id product.name,
from user_product
where user_product.user_id = 1
) as d
inner join product on product.product_id = d.product_id
inner join user on user.user_id = 1
```